# Pasar value en PHP

Tags: php, variables, post

Tengo este html el cual recoge datos de un post que se hace en un .php con anterioridad

```
    <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="div" value="<?php $division = $_POST["createDiv"]; echo $division;?>" placeholder="" disabled>
```

A su vez, este form se manda a otro .php y necesito arrastrar el `$_POST["createDiv"];` al siguiente .php pero nombrandolo con `$_POST["div"]` no funciona.

¿Como podría hacerlo?

Gracias

Edito con parte del formulario que quiero mandar.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="insertActa.php" method="post" >

<table class="" width="95%" height="200%" align="center" cellspacing="50" cellpading="100" border="0">

<!-- Fila 1 del registro -->

<div class="container">
<div class="form-row" class="center-block">

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">

        <label for="inputName"><b>Nombre division</b></label>

        <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="div" value="<?php $division = $_POST['createDiv']; echo $division;?>" placeholder="">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="inputSurname1"><b>Jornada</b></label>
        <input  type="number" class="form-control" name="jor" min="1" max="18" required>
        </div>
```

Y lo quiero recibir en el php del action, la manera de recibirlo me es indiferente, estoy probando con:

```
echo '¡Hola ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["div"]) . '!';
```

Comment: Desde un archivo php no se hace un post a una vista. Necesitariamos ver más código del que has puesto empezando por el php desde el que quieres mostrar la vista y como le pasas la variable.

Comment: No te funciona porque el input esta disabled. Los input disabled no se envian.

Comment: @JDev voy a probar quitando el disabled a ver si lo envia, gracias.

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia creo que no es necesario poner todo el codigo, ya que es un código muy extenso con muchas sentencias, he puesto de manera resumida el input que quiero mandar, luego la manera de recibirlo en el otro .php pues me da igual, aun que sea imprimiendolo con un simple echo

Comment: @JDev sigue sin funcionar, devuelve error de undefined index, creo que ese no es el problema si no el metodo con el que mandarlo.

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia editado

Comment: En el html, en el input con nombre "div" consigues imprimir la variable $division? Porque si eso es así el post te debería de llegar al siguiente php

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia si, consigo imprimir la variable sin problema, pero a la hora de mandarlo al siguiente php me da un error

Comment: @JaviTercero puedes probar cambiando el nombre del input no vaya a ser que por alguna razón tome "div" como algo reservado.

Comment: @JDev sigue igual, he cambiado el nombre pero no funciona... ¿No podria mandarlo con un SESSION?

Comment: ¿Cómo envías los datos cuando haces el POST? ¿Es mediante JSON o con un submit normal?

Comment: puedes ponernos el codigo fuente que te genera el navegador cuando visitas esa pagina? el que te genera, no el tuyo. Lo digo porque me da la sensación que `$_POST["createDiv"]` te llega vacio,  el value del input queda vacio, y luego cuando lo envias te llega... vacio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el error te viene a la hora de imprimir la variable ya que tienes el echo así:

```
 <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="div" value="<?php $division = $_POST["createDiv"]; echo $division;?>" placeholder="" disabled>
```

Y deberías cambiar las comillas dobles por simples para que no se mezclen con el html:

```
<input  type="text" class="form-control" name="div" value="<?php echo $_POST['createDiv'] ?>" placeholder="" disabled>
```

Comment: Ahora si que si, muchisimas gracias de verdad, me estaba volviendo loco...